xampp virtual host is not pointing to the site page, always redirecting to xampp dashboard
I've established a virtual host for my Wordpress website in XAMPP, every time I try to visit it, I'm automatically directed to the XAMPP dashboard page.
I tried lot of things after google search. but nothing worked. I am stuck in this.
I've done the following steps:

added in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
127.0.0.1       lh.partners.wsjcs-dev.com

Update Apache VHOST directives in C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf


<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName lh.partners.wsjcs-dev.com
  #ServerAlias lh.sponsor.wsjcs-dev.com partners.wsjcs-dev.com go.wsjcs-dev.com sponsoredcontent.wsjcs-dev.com sbx.wsjcs-dev.com demo.wsjcs-dev.com adunits.wsjcs-dev.com dev2.wsjcs-dev.com
  ServerAlias lh.*.wsjcs-dev.com
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/trust-vip-wordpress"

  #CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/apache2/wsjcs-dev.com.access_log 3600" combined
  #ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/apache2/wsjcs-dev.com.error_log 3600"

  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/trust-vip-wordpress">
    Options -Indexes
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


Have you checked the apache error log ? Also check the WordPress .htaccess
